# Trying to use Scrollbar in selectbox container Hides container

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

[Here's my example.](http://www.tomryandesign.com/dev/selectbox/)

I'm using a slightly modified version of the selectbox plugin. One of the modifications I've made is to add a class that restricts the height of the options container and adds a scrollbar when it would otherwise be more than 50% of the height of the nearest relatively positioned parent. But now when I try to click and drag the scrollbar in the container (particularly in IE and Chrome), the container disappears as if I've clicked outside of it.

Is there a way to detect when the focus is on the scrollbar? Or is there any other modification to the plugin you could recommend that would keep the options from disappearing until one is selected or there really is a click event outside the container?

Comment: The `selectbox` plugin doesn't even load in Firefox. Also, there is a syntax error. What have you done so far to try and fix this?

Comment: I've been working on it continuously since I posted this question. You may have seen it in a state of flux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by adding these lines to the selectbox plugin:

```
$container
.mousedown(function (e) {
    hasfocus = 1;
})
.mousemove(function (e) {
    hasfocus = 0;
})
.scroll(function (e) {
    $input.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have it set to hide the selectbox when you click outside of the created ul. Change it to hide when you click out of `.selectbox-wrapper`.